# Problems with a for loop/ if statement in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my code is as follows:

## having given DataFrame

```
df.head(3)

           1. open  2. high  3. low 4. close  5. volume
date                    
2021-02-18  241.80  243.93  240.86  243.79  16925563.0
2021-02-17  241.32  244.31  240.94  244.20  21451617.0
2021-02-16  245.03  246.13  242.92  243.70  26728487.0
```

I added a new column comparing "4.close" with previous day "4.close". That worked.

```
for i in df["4. close"]:
    df["changeAbsolute"] = df["4. close"] - df["4. close"].shift(-1)

df.head(3)

1. open     2. high     3. low  4. close    5. volume   changeAbsolute
date                        
2021-02-18  241.8000    243.93  240.86  243.79  16925563.0  -0.41
2021-02-17  241.3200    244.31  240.94  244.20  21451617.0  0.50
2021-02-16  245.0300    246.13  242.92  243.70  26728487.0  -1.29
```

Now comes my problem:

When adding another column that shows "+" if df["changeAbsolute"] is positiv, "-" if its negative, and "unch" if 0

```
for i in df["changeAbsolute"]:
    if i < 0:
        df["Change"] = "-"
    elif i > 0:
        df["Change"] = "+"
    else:
        df["Change"] = "unch"

df.head(3)

            1. open     2. high 3. low  4. close 5. volume  changeAbsolute      Change
date                            
2021-02-18  241.8000    243.93  240.86  243.79  16925563.0     -0.41             unch
2021-02-17  241.3200    244.31  240.94  244.20  21451617.0      0.50             unch
2021-02-16  245.0300    246.13  242.92  243.70  26728487.0     -1.29             unch
```

I was expecting:

```
            1. open     2. high 3. low  4. close 5. volume  changeAbsolute      Change
date                            
2021-02-18  241.8000    243.93  240.86  243.79  16925563.0     -0.41             -
2021-02-17  241.3200    244.31  240.94  244.20  21451617.0      0.50             +
2021-02-16  245.0300    246.13  242.92  243.70  26728487.0     -1.29             -
```

I changed the order in the if/elif/else statement. It didnt help. I got back only the else.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) here.

```
df['Change'] = np.sign(df['changeAbsolute']).map({1.0:'+', -1.0:'-', 0:'unch'})
```

or, using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
condList = [df['changeAbsolute']>0, df['changeAbsolute']<0]
choiceList = ['+', '-']
df['change'] = np.select(condList, choiceList, 'unch')
```

And Change this

```
for i in df["4. close"]:
    df["changeAbsolute"] = df["4. close"] - df["4. close"].shift(-1)
```

to

```
df["changeAbsolute"] = df["4. close"] - df["4. close"].shift(-1)
```

To make it more concise, you can [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) which does the same

```
df['changeAbsolute'] = df['4. close'].diff(-1)
```

---

Why your code gives wrong outputs is take a look at this example

```
df["Change"] = "-"
```

This assigns `'-'` to every value in the column.

If you want to use anyway then try this:

```
df.iloc[idx, 'change'] = '-' # idx is the index of the row
```

Comment: Thanks Chester, I will go through it to understand. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Chester I tried np.sign
It worked but I get a RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sign result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
I think its a  Nan I have in df["changeAbsolute"] (causing by the .shift).

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas you can process whole columns at a time, which is called *vectorization*.

To compute `df['changeAbsolute']`, one single action is required:

```
df["changeAbsolute"] = df["4. close"] - df["4. close"].shift(-1)
```

Then for the last column you could use `np.where`:

```
df['Change'] = np.where(df.changeAbsolute > 0, '+', np.where(
    df.changeAbsolute < 0, '-', 'unch'))
```

Comment: Cool but instead of two `np.where`, using `np.select`seems better imo.

Comment: Serge, thanks for the np.where. And thanks for the additional advice on the df["changeAbsolute"]!

Comment: Chester, I will try this too.